# Javascript true condition not detecting boolean

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I have this part of code:

```
   let values = true;

let msg = 'message1';
        if(values) {let msg = 'message2';}

        console.log(msg);
```

And I always have **message1** in console log.

As I know, the `if(values)` should satisfy the if statement for any truthy value of values including true, any non-zero number, any non-empty string value, any object or array reference, etc...

So why is it not working?

Comment: Why do you have `let msg` inside `if`? remove `let` and it'll work

Comment: damn, I removed it and it works! Hm, I thought LET if for defining variables, was not aware that it is enough to define it once. Thank you!

Comment: `let` has local scope of the inner block statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of a [variable declared using `let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) is the most inner block of code that contains it.

In your example there are two different variables named `msg`.

The first one (`let msg = 'message1') is the one printed by` console.log(msg);`.

The second one (let msg = 'message2') exists only in the block (`{...}`) where it is declared. It is destroyed when the code execution leaves the block (at `}`).
Inside that block the outer variable named `msg` is not available.

There is no need to declare a variable multiple times (unless your purpose is to get the effect you encountered now). Declare it only once, **before** it is used for the first time.

This code works as expected:

```js
let values = true;
let msg = 'message1';

if (values) {
  msg = 'message2';
}

console.log(msg);
```

You can add a `console.log()` calls inside the `if` block to check that it is executed (because the condition is `true`):

```js
let values = true;
let msg = 'message1';

if (values) {
  let msg = 'message2';
  console.log('inner: ' + msg);
}

console.log('outer: ' + msg);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no issues with `if` statement. It's correctly running but the problem is that you have defined `msg` variable again with `let msg = 'message2';`

That should be replaced with `msg = 'message2'` and it will work.

```js
let values = true;

let msg = 'message1';
if(values) {
  msg = 'message2';
}
console.log(msg);
```